# Chrome profiler Total Time is much lower than Self Time - shouldn't it be backwards?

Tags: google-chrome, profiler

I'm investigating a slow UI performance using Chrome profiler.

As I understand, `Total Time` should include `Self Time`, but I see that `Total Time` is much lower than `Self Time`.

How can this be?

Screenshot:

[image]